# Servicestack OrmLite - Execute as User/Impersonation

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-3.5, ormlite-servicestack

I am using Servicestack OrmLite as a data layer for my application (.NET C# 3.5/SQL Server).

One of the design requirements (It isn't greenfield, so it is mandatory) is to have commands executed as a particular user which has a schema attached on the SQL server side.

After creating the DbContext with OpenDbConnection() I send an `Execute as User` command to SQL server so that they are executing with the correct login, and they are switched over to the correct schema for that login.

The error I am getting back for selects against that connection later in the process is:

> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Thoughts:

- Connection pooling is losing the current user command sent to SQL server?
- Is there a built in User/schema handler extension to OrmLite that I haven't seen?
- RegisterConnection?

Thanks for your input.